# Web Service returns json or xml?

Tags: json, xml, web, service

I have .asmx web service and method. But I'm not sure returns json.

Does it return as a Json?

```
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
{ "Table": [ { "Key1": "x", "Key2": "x", "Key3": "Ads" } ], "Key4": [ { "Key41": "30", "Key42": "12", "Key43": "1" } ], "Key5": [ { "Key51": "10.4.2017 00:00:00" } ] }
</string>
```

So method result page writes that text at the top:

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
```

Can I get this data as json ?

Answer (score 0):

May help this one

```html
$cont_data = array( "Table"=>array( "Key1"=> "x", 
            "Key2"=> "x", 
            "Key3"=> "Ads" 
         ),
         "Key4"=>array( 
                    "Key41"=> "30", 
                    "Key42"=> "12", 
                    "Key43"=> "1" 
             ), 
         "Key5"=>array( 
                "Key51"=>"10.4.2017 00:00:00" 
            ) 
  );
  
  return json_encode($cont_data);
```

You can get the result as json, **json_decode()** do this.

Comment: No. I want to return type. Is xml or json

Comment: Updated the answer.